# How to recognize a ‘system cabinet’: /System, /Templates, /Resources etc

Tags: documentum

There are ‘system cabinets’ in Documentum Servers: /System, /Templates, /Resources. webtop_userguide.pdf specifies these 3 ones; but does not specify full list of them. Is there a way to know: is given cabinet ‘system’ or no? I am writing an application whose users will definitely have no need to look at the ‘system cabinets’.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify system cabinets by looking at their creator. The name of the creator matches your docbase name. If you want to hide cabinets from the users view, you can do this by setting a_is_hidden attribute to true. You can do this either by dql, api or from the properties dialog in DA.